# React Native Installing Ruby Gems

Tags: reactjs, ruby, react-native, macos, homebrew

When i run npx react-native init Project for create new React Native project i get this error:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching rexml 3.2.6
Installing rexml 3.2.6
Fetching CFPropertyList 3.0.6
Installing CFPropertyList 3.0.6
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.2.2
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.2.2
Fetching i18n 1.14.1
Installing i18n 1.14.1
Fetching minitest 5.20.0
Installing minitest 5.20.0
Fetching tzinfo 2.0.6
Installing tzinfo 2.0.6
Fetching zeitwerk 2.6.11
Installing zeitwerk 2.6.11
Fetching activesupport 6.1.7.6
Installing activesupport 6.1.7.6
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.7
Installing public_suffix 4.0.7
Fetching addressable 2.8.5
Installing addressable 2.8.5
Fetching httpclient 2.8.3
Installing httpclient 2.8.3
Fetching json 2.6.3
Installing json 2.6.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/qrivnel/Desktop/Project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20230924-69529-n3hcgy.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/Users/qrivnel/Desktop/Project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/Users/qrivnel/Desktop/Project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10:
fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10:
note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/qrivnel/Desktop/Project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.3 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/qrivnel/Desktop/Project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/json-2.6.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (2.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.6.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.13.0, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.13.0, which depends on
      algoliasearch was resolved to 1.27.5, which depends on
        json
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I install cocoapods with brew install cocoapods.
pod --version
1.13.0

I also tryed sudo gem install cocapods before brew install and i got this:
`
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.1/ext/ffi_c
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20230924-70457-cgucg.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-ffi_c-dir
--without-ffi_c-dir
--with-ffi_c-include
--without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
--with-ffi_c-lib
--without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
--enable-system-libffi
--disable-system-libffi
--with-libffi-config
--without-libffi-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in` block in try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in` try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in` try_ldflags'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config' from extconf.rb:9:in` system_libffi_usable?'
from extconf.rb:46:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.1/gem_make.out

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade the ruby version of your **mac**. For that:

1. install rbenv and init rbenv

```
# install rbenv
$ brew install rbenv

# init rbenv bash
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ source .zshrc
```

2. download the latest ruby version

```
# find the latest stable version
$ rbenv install --list

# install the latest version
$ rbenv install 3.2.2
```

3. make the install version global

```
$ rbenv global 3.2.2
```

4. install cocoapods

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**HTH**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue like you today, so I'm going to tell you step by step what I had to do to get my RN "Hello world" app running, hopefully you won't have to do all of them to get your app running.

Problem you are encountering is that you are probably using the system Ruby version preinstalled on macOS (which is an old version of Ruby).
You can check that by running

`ruby -v`

it's going to show something like 2.6.2 (currently my OS Ruby version)
You can install your own version of Ruby using rbenv (there are other Ruby managers as well): https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Basically you do this (you have to have installed homebrew: https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

rbenv init

rbenv install 3.2.2

rbenv rehash
```

And then type this to your terminal to add a line to .zshrc (or .bashrc, it depends on shell you are using):

```
echo 'eval "$(~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init - zsh)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

If you restart your terminal, you should be able to see 3.2.2 (or whatever version you installed) ruby version when you type `ruby -v`

Next thing what you need is cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

So if you type `pod --version` in your terminal it should show the current version, but it can show a "Bad CPU type in executable" error. This can happen if you are trying to do a command on M1 chip that is based on older Intel chip. To tackle this, install Rossetta 2: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable

Just type in the terminal this:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Now you should be able to do `pod --version` and `pod install`

After all of this, there is still one issue with activesupport, which is part of cocoapods. Problem is CocoaPods isn't using an exact version of the activesupport gem and while it needs 7.0.8 it's pulling in 7.1.0 which breaks things. I found a solution to this here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39832

I'm just going to copy paste the solution from the link (Author: stephen-pearce) here:

Update the Gemfile in the root with the following:

```
gem 'activesupport', '~> 7.0', '<= 7.0.8'
```

Then run `bundle update --bundler` in the root then `bundle install` and `bundle exec pod install` in the ios directory and everything should work.

Hopefully this helped you solve your problem, or that you didn't have to do all of these steps to get your RN app running.

Comment: Upvoted. Thank you very much! I personally just needed to make: `rbenv init`, `rbenv install 3.2.2` and `sudo gem install cocoapods` to resolved the problem. I previously watched other guides before landing here, so it may explain why I could have skip every other steps of your answer.